# Group by event using row_number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data 
(
    Event_Date date,
    Person_ID varchar(1), 
    Event_flag varchar(1)
)

INSERT INTO #Data (Event_date, Person_ID, Event_flag)
VALUES
    ('20190910', 'A', 'X'),
    ('20190911', 'A', 'X'),
    ('20190912', 'A', 'Y'),
    ('20190913', 'A', 'X'),
    ('20190914', 'A', 'X'),
    ('20190915', 'A', 'X'),
    ('20190916', 'A', 'Y')
```

How to get result using row_number or loop, to get same row_numbers by the same event, just on other event row_number get +1

```
Person_ID   Event_flag  Rn
--------------------------
A           X           1
A           X           1
A           Y           2
A           X           3
A           X           3
A           X           3
A           Y           4
```

Comment: How should your result be ordered ? By date ?

Comment: @VBoka yes, I order by date

Comment: Are you sure you are using Postgres? Because there `#Data` is an invalid identifier and you can't create a table with that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate that the counter in the expected `Rn` column should increment by one each time the event flag changes value, for a given person, as ordered by the event date.  We can use `LAG` here to construct an increment column, which when summed by event date, will generate the sequence you want.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN Event_flag =
              LAG(Event_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY Person_ID ORDER BY Event_date)
                   THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flag
    FROM Data
)

SELECT Event_date, Person_ID, Event_flag,
       SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY Event_date) AS Rn
FROM cte
ORDER BY Event_date;
```

### Demo